# How to change profile picture on Google?

Tags: google-account-profile

I'm trying to change my profile picture on Google, but it keeps putting my old picture over lapping my new one? I clicked on my picture and pressed change profile, and uploaded my new photo. I apparently have multiple profile pictures but I only want one. Please help me.

Answer (score -2):

Hm well I tried it again with a different photo and it worked? So lesson learned if this happens to you just try again I guess.